# Merging a LAN with home network

Tags: networking

In my house I have about eight walljacks with RJ45 ports for direct internet connection. A modem from my ISP is connected to a switch which supplies internet connection to those end points. On one of my end points in a central room I have installed a NetGear router. My TV and other devices are connected to the switch directly. 
The question is how to force my TV or other devices to connect to the internet through the NetGear router?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su] or [sf].

Comment: is router wireless or wired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the TV (or other devices) with a static IP address and set the NetGear router as the Default Gateway.